# Value Between $\alpha$ And $\beta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, chemistry

[image]

$dynamic range$ is defined as the lowest concentration at which quantitative measurements can be obtained ($LOQ$) to the concentration at which the calibration curve departs from linearity ($LOL$).

Let $\alpha = LOL$

Let $\beta = LOQ$

I have to two different approach on finding the value of the $dynamic range$. First I use subtraction,

$dynamic range$ = $\alpha$ - $\beta$.

However, the value of the $dynamic range$ results on a negative number because $\beta$ is always greater than $\alpha$.

Second, I use distance formula,

Let $(x - xo) = \alpha = LOL$

Let $(y - yo) = \beta = LOQ$

$d = \sqrt{(x - xo)^2 + (y - yo)^2}$

$d = \sqrt{(\alpha)^2 + (\beta)^2}$

I also found a value using distance formula, yet it doesn't make sense because it is outside the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

For example:
$\alpha = 4.219434974$

$\beta = 6.027764249$

$d = \sqrt{(\alpha)^2 + (\beta)^2}$

$d = \sqrt{(4.219434974)^2 + (6.027764249)^2}$

$d = 7.357823954$

Is it applicable to use the area under the curve to find the value of the $dynamic range$?

I post this question here at Math Stack Exchange because the question is more of mathematical concept rather than chemistry concept. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Does "dynamic range" have a *definition*?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson. Sorry, I haven't include the definition of dynamic range. Dynamic range is defined as the lowest concentration at which quantitative measurements can be obtained ($LOQ$) to the concentration at which the calibration curve departs from linearity ($LOL$).

Comment: When adding clarification that is essential to the post, please click on the tiny `edit` and improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "to" in that definition. How can somehting be defined as "$A$ to $B$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the relevant chemistry background, but after carefully reading your description, and it seems that the simple

$$\text{Dynamic Range}= \beta - \alpha = \text{LOL} - \text{LOQ}$$

suits your needs. So basically your first guess is no wrong, just that the roles are switched (when you denoted $\alpha$ as LOL erroneously.

Actually, it is also indicated in the diagram as the range of the horizontal double-arrow. Thus just keep it simple and stay horizontal. There's no need to use Pythagorean Theorem or whatever.